# Spring tool suite installation

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I successfully installed STS 2.9.0 on windows 7, but it is showing internal error occurred during initializing spring UAA. Please guide me how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post the full error message you are getting.

Comment: Oracle Java 8 or 9? OpenJDK?

Comment: 'Initializing spring UAA' has encountered a problem. 
An internal error occurred during "initializing Spring UAA". Org/eclipse/just/core/javamodelexception

Comment: Your version is really not supported yet.

The latest version of STS is **STS 3.9.1.RELEASE**, please download the latest version and re-install it.

Comment: There seems to be something broken with your installation. Can you please run your Eclipse with the "-clean" option once to see if that fixes the issue or just try unzipping the zipped folder again into some other folder and install. I faced the same issue it got solved with re-installation. OR update the version.

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_144 is Installed on my laptop 64 bit

Comment: How to start eclipse with -clean option in windows @astha Srivastava please help

Comment: @parth eclipse toolbar -> Project -> Clean -> select project and clean

Comment: I will just try

Answer (score 1):

To start eclipse with -clean in windows.

1. Quit Eclipse if it is running.
2. Go to the Eclipse installation directory
3. Open the file eclipse.ini in a text editor. Search for the line -vmargs
4. After the line -vmargs,
5. put -clean

Start eclipse and check if that solves the problem

Comment: There is also an error saying

Workspace configuration

An internal error occurred during "workspace configuration".
org/eclipse/jdt/launching/javaruntime

Comment: I add -clean as guided by you but it sis still showing same error

Comment: @parth I think there is problem in your unzipping of either eclipse or Spring tool. If possible do it from start with fresh software and change your spring tool version. Your installation got broke somewhere.

Comment: I tried installing other versions also 
And also tried installing it in some other directory 
But problem is not solved

Comment: With same eclipse?

Comment: I'm installing Spring too suite 
Ant different versions of it

Comment: The IDE is same, right? If in the same IDE it is giving issues the changes the IDE like using eclipse Mars or Neon version.

Comment: No the spring versions are different for different STS version

Comment: Eclipse versions are different with different STS versions

Comment: Make sure you followed all the steps correctly from here https://docs.spring.io/s2-dmserver/2.0.x/getting-started/html/ch02s03.html

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved by removing the complex directory structure,

Earlier, I was extracting to

> C:\softwares\spring-tool-suite-3.9.6.RELEASE-e4.9.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle

Changed it to

> C:\softwares\sts-bundle